# SFINAE : Know if a function already exist or no

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

Basically, I want to write code like that :

```
std::vector<float> a = { 54, 25, 32.5 };
std::vector<int> b = { 55, 65, 6 };

std::cout << a << b << std::string("lol");
```

It is not possible because there is no overload for `operator<<(ostream&, vector)`

So, I write a function that do the job :

```
template<template<typename...> typename T, typename ...Args>
std::enable_if_t<is_iterable_v<T<Args...>>>, std::ostream> &operator<<(std::ostream &out, T<Args...> const &t) {
    for (auto const &e : t)
        out << e << " ";
    out << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

That works good, but I have a problem with string. Because strings are iterable and strings HAVE `operator<<` function.

So I tested with another trait like `!is_streamable_out && _is_iterable` testing something like that : `std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>()` and if it has begin / end functions. It works good on MSVC, but not on Clang (I think it is because the compiler use the function I just create as well, so it founds one overload available for all methods).

So, I am currently using `!is_same_v<string, T>` but it is not perfect IMHO.

Is there a way to know if a function exists without redeclaring the function?

Basically, I want to do something like that

```
if function foo does not exist for this type.
then function foo for this type is ...
```

It is not the same problem as [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) because in this other thread, the function is not exactyly the same (toString vs toOptionalString). In my case, the function are the same.

Here is my full code :

```
template <class...>
struct make_void { using type = void; };

template <typename... T>
using void_t = typename make_void<T...>::type; // force SFINAE

namespace detail {
    template<typename AlwaysVoid, template<typename...> typename Operator, typename ...Args>
    struct _is_valid : std::false_type {};


    template<template<typename...> typename Operator, typename ...Args>
    struct _is_valid<void_t<Operator<Args...>>, Operator, Args...> : std::true_type { using type = Operator<Args...>; };
}

template<template<typename ...> typename Operator, typename ...Args>
using is_valid = detail::_is_valid<void, Operator, Args...>;

#define HAS_MEMBER(name, ...)\
template<typename T>\
using _has_##name = decltype(std::declval<T>().name(__VA_ARGS__));\
\
template<typename T>\
using has_##name = is_valid<_has_push_back, T>;\
\
template<typename T>\
constexpr bool has_##name##_v = has_##name<T>::value

HAS_MEMBER(push_back, std::declval<typename T::value_type>());
HAS_MEMBER(begin);
HAS_MEMBER(end);

template<typename T>
using is_iterable = std::conditional_t<has_begin_v<T> && has_end_v<T>, std::true_type, std::false_type>;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_iterable_v = is_iterable<T>::value;



template<class T, class Stream, class = void>
struct can_print : std::false_type {};

template<class T, class Stream>
struct can_print<T, Stream, void_t<decltype(std::declval<Stream&>() << std::declval<const T&>())>> : std::true_type {};

template<class T, class Stream = std::ostream>
constexpr bool can_print_v = can_print<T, Stream>::value;

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_iterable_v<T> && !can_print_v<T>, std::ostream> &operator<<(std::ostream &out, T const &t) {
    for (auto const &e : t)
        out << e << " ";
    out << std::endl;
    return out;
}

template<typename A, typename B>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, std::pair<A, B> const &p) {
    out << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;
    return out;
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<has_push_back_v<T>, T> &operator<<(T &c, typename T::value_type const &e) {
    c.push_back(e);
    return c;
}
```

and the main :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Tools/stream.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::vector<float> a = { 54, 25, 32.5 };
    std::vector<int> b = { 55, 65, 6 };

    std::cout << a;

    std::cout << has_push_back<float>::value  << " " << has_push_back<std::vector<float>>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_iterable<std::vector<float>>::value << " " << is_iterable<float>::value << std::endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::enable_if_t` didn't exist until C++14, so is your code really C++11?

Comment: it is possible to implement it in C++11, so it is possible to answer this question with C++11 as well. However, yes, the code is C++14 (even C++1z with Clang)

Comment: Not related to your direct question, but why are you bothering with `...Args` at all? Your function would work fine as a simple `template<typename T>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

Comment: @Frank because containers have multiple template arguments : one for the type, but other for allocator, keys (for map or other) etc etc

Comment: I don't think this should be possible. If you think of it - it would mean that the function should exist only if function does. But then the function should not exist as it exists...

Comment: @Antoine Morrier but `template<typename T>` matches *any* type, templated or not: https://pastebin.com/jqYBsvRK

Comment: @Frank it is a good question, I will see if it is possible or if there is problem with that :p. Thanks for this advice :)

Yes you are right

Comment: Possibly the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912283/how-to-avoid-this-sentence-is-false-in-a-template-sfinae which also provides a clever solution that avoids your problem entirely.  As an aside, I find overloading operators on types you do not own to be impolite (bad form), so I wouldn't do this: what happens when C++20 adds `<<` to vector in a different format?  Doing so outside the type's namespace is even worse, as now it only works in the namespace where you overloaded `<<`.

Comment: I'd consider doing a `std::cout << stream_range( v, ',' );` instead, where `stream_range` takes an iterable range and streams it separated by `,`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to avoid this sentence is false in a template SFINAE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912283/how-to-avoid-this-sentence-is-false-in-a-template-sfinae) provides an answer that solves your problem -- overload `<<(ostream&, Ts...)`, which will be found with lower priority than any other `<<` overload.

At the same time I'd say your plan is a poor one.  Overloading operators for `std` types is a bad plan for 2 reasons.

First, you should be reluctant to overload operators for types you do not own unless there is a great reason.

Second, if you do so, you should do it in the namespace of the type, and you cannot inject your `<<` into `namespace std` without making your program ill-formed.

Operators overloaded in a namespace different than the types in question can only be found in the namespace where you did the overload.  Operators overloaded in a namespace related to the arguments can be found anywhere.

This results in fragile `<<` that only works in one namespace.

---

So, instead, do this:

```
struct print_nothing_t {};
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, print_nothing_t) {
  return os;
}
template<class C, class Sep=print_nothing_t>
struct stream_range_t {
  C&& c;
  Sep s;
  template<class T=print_nothing_t>
  stream_range_t( C&& cin, T&& sin = {} ):
    c(std::forward<C>(cin)),
    s(std::forward<T>(sin))
  {}
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, stream_range_t&& self) {
    bool first = true;
    for (auto&& x:self.c) {
      if (!first) os << self.s;
      os << decltype(x)(x);
      first = false;
    }
    return os;
  }
};
template<class C, class Sep = print_nothing_t>
stream_range_t<C, Sep> stream_range( C&& c, Sep&& s={} ) {
  return {std::forward<C>(c), std::forward<Sep>(s)};
}
```

Now, if you want nested vectors to work, you'd have to implement a stream range that applies an adapter to its contents.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfdc13cfe33f80e1) with this test code:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};
std::cout << stream_range(v, ',') << "\n";
```

output is `1,2,3,4`.

---

How to make this recursive:

We can write a `adapt_for_streaming` function that dispatches to either `identity` (for things already streamable), and to `stream_range` for things iterable but not already streamable.

Users can then add new `adapt_for_streaming` overloads for other types.

`stream_range_t` then streams using `adapt_for_streaming` on its contents.

Next, we can add tuple/pair/array overloads to `adapt_for_streaming` and suddenly `std::vector< std::vector< std::tuple<std::string, int> > >` can be streamed.

End users can call `stream_range` directly, or `adapt_for_streaming`, to string an iterable container.  You can even call `stream_range` directly on a `std::string` to treat it like a streamable collection of `char` instead of a string.

Comment: The "This sentence is false" was just blowing my mind the more I thought about my answer. I think OP wants the nice `stream << T` syntax, but we can't get it with SFINAE without ending up in this true/false scenario.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a small detection idiom that tests if the expression `stream << value` is well formed*.

Here it is using `std::ostream`:

```
template<class...>
using void_t = void;

template<class T, class Stream, class=void>
struct can_print : std::false_type{};

template<class T, class Stream>
struct can_print<T, Stream, void_t<decltype(std::declval<Stream&>() << std::declval<const T&>())>> : std::true_type{};

template<class T, class Stream=std::ostream>
constexpr bool can_print_v = can_print<T, Stream>::value;
```

Now your can write your overload for `operator<<` like so:

```
template<template<class...> class C, class...T>
std::enable_if_t<!can_print_v<C<T...>>, std::ostream>& operator<<(std::ostream &out, C<T...> const &t) {
    for (auto const &e : t)
        out << e << " ";
    out << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

and a test

```
std::vector<float> a = { 54, 25, 32.5 };
std::vector<int> b = { 55, 65, 6 };
std::cout << a;
std::cout << b;
std::cout << std::string("lol") << std::endl;
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oUPO7CGbKpO9LJ1L)

---

Yakk points out an interesting thing in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45088196/27678). [This sentence is false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15912283/27678).

Basically, by using `!can_print_v` to enable an overload for `operator<<`, the `can_print_v` should subsequently be `true`, but it's `false` because the first instantiation of the template resulted in the struct deriving from `std::false_type`. Subsequent tests for `can_print_v` are therefore invalid.

I'm leaving this answer as a cautionary tale. The trait itself is okay, but using it to SFINAE something that invalidates the trait is not okay.

<sup>*It appears OP has copied this code into their own codebase and then modified the question to include it, in case you were wondering why it looks the other way around</sup>

Comment: That is what I tried with the "is_streamable out" mentioned in my question and it does not work on Clang. Only on MSVC.

Comment: The problem is use `can_print_v()` to sfinae enable the definition of `operator<<()` when `can_print_v()` is false; with a similar solution my compiler goes in loop.

Comment: @max66: Updated with fuller example.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier: Can you elaborate? I was using clang in my demo.

Comment: I am using the same solution as yours or almost :
`std::enable_if_t<is_iterable_v<T> && !can_print_v<T>, std::ostream> &operator<<(std::ostream &out, T const &t)`.

When I try to read a std::string, there is no problem now.  But when I am using a std::vector<> there is one. Because clang seems to find the function even if it is not built yet.

Comment: I add a full code in my question I am using clang C2 (inside visual studio)

Comment: my g++ (6.3.0) compile your example but from clang++ (3.8.1) I get the following error "fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 256"; same error that I get from a similar solution based on constexpr functions. I don't know how right (g++ or clang++)

Comment: @max66: It looks like it only works on clang 3.9.1 and up. It appears that this has to do with the contradiction of using `!can_print_v` to SFINAE a function that would make `!can_print_v` `false`.

Comment: You're right: starting from 3.9.1 works my solution too. Interesting.