# Overriding operator<< for all types

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, overloading, name-lookup

I'm a bit annoyed with compilation errors which arise when I try to write `std::cout << x`, and left shift operator it not defined for `x`. Can't convert x to this, can't convert x to that... Several screens of useless error messages.

I want to specialize `operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&)` for all types which do not yet have such operator defined. Inside I could put a, say, static assert and make compilation error message much clearer than it is now.

My first attempt was the following.

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct Has : public std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct Has<T, decltype(void(
            std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>()
))> : public std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T&)
    -> typename std::enable_if<
        !Has<T>::value,
        std::ostream&>::type
{
    return out << "my operator";
}
```

It fails to compile because maximum template depth is exceeded. Indeed, my `operator<<` calls to `Has` specialization which in order calls to `operator<<`, where my overload is examined once again, so on, so on, so on.

The simplest version doesn't work as well: ambiguous overload for `std::ostream& << const char*`. Well, expected.

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T&)
{
    return out << "my operator";
}
```

How can I accomplish the task? Or, in general, how can I define the function for all argument types but for those which can already be passed to the function?

Comment: [Barber paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Not exactly. In terms of barber it looks like 'This evening the barber will shave everybody who hasn't yet shaven themselves'. I want to define the function for all types that are not accepted by the function _elsewhere_. I see no paradox here.

Comment: It would be difficult, perhaps impossible, to use such an operator in a well-formed program. The definition of your operator, should you succeed in pulling it off, would depend on exactly which specializations happen to be visible at its point of instantiation. Which could be different in different translation unis and even within a single translation unit (per **[temp.point]/8**), which would be an ODR violation, rendering the program ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh, well... Thanks for the link, I'll read the standard and either understand the absurdity of my question or reword it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912283/how-to-avoid-this-sentence-is-false-in-a-template-sfinae is not a direct answer, but covers some of the same issues.  A workaround where you somehow make your `<<` "less attractive" rather than test for `<<` itself might work; alternatively, you can write your own streaming operator that falls back on `<<` if it exists, and otherwise generates a static assert.

Comment: How about using different name ? `template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<Has<T>::value> print(std::ostream& out, const T&t) {return out << t;}` and similar for `std::enable_if_t<!Has<T>::value>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 No. I want to use `<<` but be warned if I accidentally use it with an incompatible type. I tried to reason it in the comments to the answer.

Comment: And Yakk suggests nearly the same think in response to your comment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot.  But this is [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), so you can if you are willing to be evil.

```
namespace named_operator {
  template<class D>struct make_operator{constexpr make_operator(){}};

  template<class T, char, class O> struct half_apply { T&& lhs; O const& o; };

  template<class Lhs, class Op>
  half_apply<Lhs, '<', Op> operator<( Lhs&& lhs, make_operator<Op>const & o ) {
    return {std::forward<Lhs>(lhs), o};
  }

  template<class Lhs, class Op, class Rhs>
  auto operator<( half_apply<Lhs, '<', Op>&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs )
  -> decltype( named_invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), lhs.o, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) ) )
  {
    return named_invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), lhs.o, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) );
  }
}
namespace utility {
  namespace details {
    template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
  }
  template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename details::voider<Ts...>::type;
  namespace details {

    template<template<class...>class, class, class...>
    struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
    template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
    struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
  }
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;
}
namespace streaming {
  namespace details {
    template<class T>
    using ostream_r = decltype( std::cout << std::declval<T&&>() );
  }
  template<class T>
  using can_ostream = utility::can_apply<details::ostream_r, T>;

  struct out_tag: named_operator::make_operator<out_tag> {};
  static const out_tag out;
  template<class T>
  std::ostream& named_invoke( std::ostream& os, out_tag, T const& t ) {
    static_assert( can_ostream<T const&>{}, "This type cannot be streamed" );
    return os<<t;
  }
  template<class T,
    std::enable_if_t< can_ostream<T const&>{}, int> =0 // breaks MSVC
  >
  std::ostream& named_invoke( std::ostream& os, out_tag, T const& t ) {
    return os<<t;
  }
}
```

and if I wrote that right,

```
struct no_worky {};
no_worky bob;
using streaming::out;
std::cout <out< bob;
```

fails to compile and generates a friendly message, meanwhile

```
std::cout <out< 7;
```

calls `std::cout << 7`.

I don't think this is worth it.

Comment: I've just examined these named operators following the link from your profile :) It's a really nifty thing from the dark side of C++. Though it doesn't solve my problem right. In fact, here is the rationale: I'm doing competitive programming, and those seconds you spend on finding out why your code doesn't compile are precious. So I need not a production-quality solution but an ad-hoc hack that will warn me about cout-ing std::vector and doesn't need to take into account ODR, multiple translation units and similar. The question you linked to might help, I'm examining it at the moment.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov Then write `print(ostream&, Args const&...)` instead of using `<<`?

Answer (score 0):

One answer may be to wrap the ostream in a thin wrapper for the piping operation?

This thin wrapper can have the universal template operator << member,
that in turn checks for the real operators on the wrapped std::ostream.
You may find that you get an even less pleasant error message, though!

Note that you also need to add a specific handler for std::endl and its kin, as they expect to specialise on stream width, which you have obfuscated.